# Shotcuts in immunity debugger

Tags: ollydbg, immunity-debugger

Recently I started using Immunity Debugger instead of Olly where I got really got used to my custom keybidings. I could not seem to find an option to configure shortcuts/keybindings in immunity debugger.

**Do you know how to use custom keybinds in immdbg? Any external tool/plugin for this purpose?**